# css3 linear gradient color stop works differently on webkit

Tags: css, webkit, cross-browser

refer to: [www.get-offit.com](http://get-offit.com)

Go to where the book cover almost ends and the background color changes:

We have:

```
html {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 500px, #EEEEEE 0px);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 500px, #EEEEEE 0px);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 500px, #EEEEEE 0px);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(5, #FFFFFF), to(#EEEEEE));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 500px, #EEEEEE 0px);
background: linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 500px, #EEEEEE 0px);
```

}

If you open the site with firefox, you get a clear cut line between the white and the gray without any gradients going on:

[image: firefox screenshot]

If you open the site with chrome, you get a 5px'ish gray gradient where the white ends and the gray begins:

[image: chrome screenshot]

How do I make it so that the colors stop abruptly without going showing actual gradients on webkit browsers as it currently does on firefox?

Cheers
G

Comment: I haven't tried it but could it help to add a "color-stop" in either white or gray, and center it on the transition?

Comment: can you show me a sample of that?

Comment: I don't understand why you're using a CSS gradient here.

Comment: the idea was to play around with the possibilities of the gradient rule, including this color stop which I then wanted to follow up with actual gradients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From some attempts to reproduce this in a test case, it appears the issue may be that Webkit's implementation has trouble calculating the exact height of `html` when there's no height specified directly. Setting a `height` of 100% or a fixed pixel height seems to clear it up. However I doubt that's a practical solution. In my own use I've not noticed this as an issue with other elements, so maybe it's particular to the use of a linear-gradient on `html`.

If it is a bug with Webkit, then your best solution maybe to rework your css so that the grey background can be applied to an element. Obviously that's a big change to accomodate Webkit, but it would also make the background compatible with older versions of IE as well.

Comment: I tried both height:100%; and height:1000px; for html {} and there's no visible change. I will continue doing tests

Comment: @Sotkra I was seeing the same problem when I tested it. It's looking more like it might be a Webkit bug since Firefox handles it fine.

Comment: yeah it's really making me wonder. Have you seen cases where webkit handles these kinds of 'raw' color stops properly?

Comment: I have, but at small sizes. This is a pretty enormous gradient.

Answer (score 5):

Try using this css tool at Microsoft's site (Yep, Microsoft):

http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/cssgradientbackgroundmaker/default.html

It will help generate cross-browser css code (not just IE) and could also come in handy with changing up the gradient effects a bit. You can add more gradient points and even try different colors.

Here's a code sample from the online tool:

```
/* IE10 */ 
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #EEEEEE 100%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #EEEEEE 100%);

/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #EEEEEE 100%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1, #EEEEEE));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #EEEEEE 100%);

/* Proposed W3C Markup */ 
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #EEEEEE 100%);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a difference between webkit & gecko. Unfortunately on such large gradient sizes it looks like webkit takes the 'fast' route for rendering enormous gradients (don't forget that gradients are **browser-generated images**) and throws in some vagueness to it.

Try using `background-position-y: 500px;` to force the gradient to begin 500px from the top in webkit.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ampp/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient( top, #FFFFFF 500px, #EEEEEE 520px );
```

Comment: well, the issue here is with webkit but... adding 520px to the #eee part of the declaration does not yield the intended effect

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to leave the gradient aside if you want to achieve the solid transition from #fff to #eee in webkit. If you set your css up like this

```
html {
   background: #eee; 
   }

   body {
      background: #fff;
      height: 500px;
      }
```

it will replicate what you are trying to achieve using the gradient. (See screen shot) It will also be cross browser compatible. I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: I know that, this question revolves around cross-browser differences in linear-gradient implementation rather than 'how do I achieve x effect'.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in all browsers:

```
html {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 500px, #EEEEEE 0px);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 500px, #EEEEEE 0px);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 500px, #EEEEEE 0px);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF 500px, #EEEEEE 0px);
background: linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 500px, #EEEEEE 0px);
}
```

Although a gradient is not needed for the effect you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

As egid stated, chrome does take the fast route for rendering gradients. see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627292/) and [this pen](http://codepen.io/elliz/pen/fCsay) for a cool animated demonstration.