# Webkit linear gradient stops render incorrectly

Tags: css, webkit, linear-gradients

I have come across a weird problem in webkit browsers (Chrome, Opera).

Test case: http://sample.easwee.net/gradient-bug/ (check in Chrome or latest Opera)

I have two columns wrapped by a container. I'm applying a CSS gradient to create backgrounds for this two columns. The color stop is set to `66%` and columns have the same `66%` width (using padding to offset the right column).

It renders correctly in Firefox - both column layout and gradient stop point match, but in webkit based browsers the color stop is not matching the column width, although I've used `66%`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="special-container">
    <div class="special-container-inner">
        <div class="special-container-column-L">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1070x600" />
        </div>
        <div class="special-container-column-R">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/530x345" />
            <h3>Test</h3>
            <p>It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.special-container {}
.special-container-inner {max-width:1600px;margin:0 auto;
    background: #ff0000;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 66%, #2989d8 66%, #2989d8 66%, #2989d8 100%, #207cca 100%, #7db9e8 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#ff0000), color-stop(66%,#ff0000), color-stop(66%,#2989d8), color-stop(66%,#2989d8), color-stop(100%,#2989d8), color-stop(100%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 66%,#2989d8 66%,#2989d8 66%,#2989d8 100%,#207cca 100%,#7db9e8 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 66%,#2989d8 66%,#2989d8 66%,#2989d8 100%,#207cca 100%,#7db9e8 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 66%,#2989d8 66%,#2989d8 66%,#2989d8 100%,#207cca 100%,#7db9e8 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #ff0000 0%,#ff0000 66%,#2989d8 66%,#2989d8 66%,#2989d8 100%,#207cca 100%,#7db9e8 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=1 );
}

.special-container-column-L {width:66%;float:left;text-align:right;}
.special-container-column-L img {display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;max-width:100%;opacity:0.8;}
.special-container-column-R {padding-left:66%;}
.special-container-column-R img {display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;max-width:100%;width:100%;opacity:0.9;}
.clear {clear:both;}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I've used [Colorzilla generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to generate the gradient.

**Are there any bug reports or workarounds for this kind of problem?**

Comment: 1070px is not 66% of 1600px...it's 66.875%. Rounding?

Comment: @Paulie_D I thought that first too, but it is not related to rounding. Infact the `.875%` difference does not make up for such a big gap.

Comment: Interesting though how the gap comes and goes when you resize the window: http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/feckH

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah - that behavior is totally odd.

Comment: You had the #2989d8 66% colour stop in twice, but that did not appear to be the reason. I am getting some stepping in http://codepen.io/elliz/pen/sIGBh

Comment: Looks like rounding errors - I have reduced the issue, but not fully fixed. Workaround: have gutter between columns and hide the error in that.

Comment: @Ruskin In this situation I could not use gutters. I am however still looking for a bug report or any mention of this problem.

Comment: I have simplified to simplest case - still issue in chrome: http://codepen.io/elliz/pen/fCsay (in chrome 35)

Comment: @Ruskin Case shows it nicely. Gy

Comment: @easwee, thanks I had fun making the animated div to avoid people needing to resize the window ;) worth a vote up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update 2015-11-25

A fix for this is finally in the pipeline - see https://codereview.chromium.org/1457783005.

### tl;dr;

It is a <strike>bug</strike> feature in chrome.

### Details

I have simplified my test cases massively at http://codepen.io/elliz/pen/fCsay and it still appears to be an issue in Chrome - and I have found a bug report (below).

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        Try resizing this page, the border between two colours should be smooth in most browsers, but will jump around in Chrome.   
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #c93 66%, #2989d8 66%);
}

.wrapper div {
  width:66%;
  border-right: 1px dotted white;
}
```

May have to go back to using Faux Columns or other old-school designs ... or if your user-base only uses the latest browsers try out the new shiny and use flexbox ;)

#### Edit

I found a bug at - http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=233879 and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=281489

> [skia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skia_Graphics_Engine) discretizes the colors into 256 levels for (lots of) speed. hard-edged
>   gradients like this (where there are two colors at the same color-stop)
>   definitely show up this limitation. We can look at ways to increase
>   precision, but there will be a real performance cost, so we have to decide
>   how important this particular behavior is in practice.

Comment: UPDATE: Google appear to have changed the status on the bug ... maybe someone is working on it !?

Comment: yeah they did - sadly to untriaged, so this will probably be around for a long time.

Comment: Still unfixed and sure is annoying