# Webkit fails with smooth gradient rendering

Tags: css, webkit, gradient

After creating some small elements with linear-gradient background I was "surprised" by their smoothless appearance in webkit browsers (chrome, safari, opera), while FF and IE are doing well. Vendor prefixes didn't help.

Small example:

```
background: linear-gradient(30deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 30.5%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 31%);
```

Actually, nothing to explain here - just try and see
http://jsfiddle.net/p7qp1mmh/

Is it curable or should I just give it up?

Comment: Usually `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` does the trick, not sure what's going on there but it could be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627292/webkit-linear-gradient-stops-render-incorrectly

Comment: @DeeMac Looked through the topic. Seems it's a long story and I there's nothing to do in my case. well, hope I'm wrong.